# Expectation of products of (in)dependent random variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, independence

Let $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ be random variables and we are interested in $\mathbb{E}[X_1 X_2 Y_1 Y_2]$. How can we dissect this expectation if:

1. $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$ and $Y_1$ is independent of $Y_2$?
2. If the same holds as above, i.e., $X_1$ is independent of $X_2$ and $Y_1$ is independent of $Y_2$, but additionally also $X_i$ in independent of $Y_j$ for $i \neq j$?
3. If a new random variable $X$ is independent of another random variable $Y$, is then also $X^2$ independent of $Y$? I.e., does it hold, that $\mathbb{E}[X^2 Y] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] \mathbb{E}[Y]$?

Comment: Answer to (3) is 'yes', because functions of independent random variables are also independent.